# Struggling with new HDD sector alignment - parted likes it, fdisk and mkfs do not

Tags: fdisk, parted

I just attached a new 2TB HDD to an SBC running Ubuntu.  There is no data on the HDD and so I can freely wipe it as needed as the OS is running on an SDCard.  I want to format it as one large partition.  I have done the following:

```
parted --align optimal /dev/sda
(parted) mklabel gpt 
(parted) mkpart newvol 0% 100% 
(parted) align-check
alignment type(min/opt)  [optimal]/minimal? opt                           
Partition number? 1                                                       
1 aligned
```

Okay, that looks good.  Now is where it gets weird.  Look at the following:

```
sudo fdisk -lu /dev/sda
Disk /dev/sda: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 33553920 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 41C583F8-E750-4C58-A4B4-06EFAAA961FB

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1  65535 3907000094 3906934560  1.8T Linux filesystem

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

and

```
sudo mkfs.xfs -s size=4K /dev/sda1
warning: device is not properly aligned /dev/sda1
Use -f to force usage of a misaligned device
```

This misaligned message is maintained with mkfs regardless of whether I specify the -s parameter.

All of this brings me to my question.  Is my partitioned aligned or not?  Why does parted think that it is, but the other two apps suggest otherwise.  As a follow-on, what do I need to do to fix this if it does indeed need fixing?

Thank you!

Comment: If start not divisible by 8, it is not aligned. Most new drives start at sector 2048. Since gpt drive, I might try gdisk. GPT fdisk Tutorial 
http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/walkthrough.html & 
http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/ Also by same author: https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/l-4kb-sector-disks/

Answer (score 1):

From what I read, the enclosure gives false results as to the optimal_io_size. Mine was pointing to the same 65535 sector as yours for my Transcend 512GB SSD in an M.2 enclosure.

I am going by what I read in the following comment on the topic;
https://rainbow.chard.org/2013/01/30/how-to-align-partitions-for-best-performance-using-parted/#comment-9569